# eZ Publish Unable to override [UserSettings] in site.ini.append.php

Tags: php, ini, ezpublish

I am having trouble overriding [UserSettings] in the site.ini.append.php.

**[UserSettings] MaxNumberOfFailedLogin=5**

I am aware of this topic : http://share.ez.no/forums/setup-design/ini-settings-override-order which describe how to override ini files in eZ.

In the admin : http://s21.postimg.org/fcxj682yv/admin.jpg it says that the settings is override with 5.

But when i am using the ezuser class with **eZUser::maxNumberOfFailedLogin();** to get the MaxNumberOfFailedLogin it always says '0' !

If i change the settings/site.ini directly (which is not recommanded) it is working.

Isn't the ezuser class aware of the overriding system of eZ Publish ? What should i do ?

Thanks for help. Cheers.

Comment: Is the issue in a CLI script ? are you in the right siteaccess ?

Comment: No and Yes. I have found a way to turn around it. (posting it now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do otherwise :

As the **eZUser** class is using the **eZINI** class to get properties in the site.ini file, in order to get overrided properties, instead of using eZINI::instance(); you have to set **eZINI::instance('site.ini.append.php', 'settings/override');** with the overrided file.

This way you can use overrided conf.

Only problem, you will have to call eZINI each time you need an overrided conf. (in this case for eZUser).